# Generate PDF from docbook XML when building Java project using Gradle

Tags: xml, pdf, gradle, docbook, multiplatform

I need to generate a PDF version of the docbook.xml documentation (5.0) when building the java project using gradle (build.gradle file).

If someone could show an example of a script that will work on any platform (Mac OS X, Windows, Linux) that would be very helpful.

Comment: See this post, I think it answers your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615002/how-to-generate-pdf-from-docbook-5-0

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had seen this post before but didn't read it carefully. I will update as soon as I have tested it.

Comment: Ok, just double checked. It is useful information, however it doesn't say anything about gradle. I just found something in the gradle source files and am testing it, will post something if it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so finally I found the solution. In order to generate a PDF, you have to provide the following files :

- The docbook file (.XML)
- An XSL stylesheet file (.XSL)
- The docbook.gradle file that you can grab from here: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-build-gradle/blob/master/docbook.gradle
- The build.gradle file

You have to add after to build.gradle the line

```
apply from: "docbook.gradle"
```

after

```
apply plugin: "java"
```

Then, append to the end of build.gradle this:

```
docbookPdf {
    sourceFileName = "docbook.xml"
    stylesheet = file("doc/docbook-style.xsl")
    sourceDirectory = file( "doc" )
    docsDir = new File(project.getBuildDir(), "docs");
}
```

Here, we've put the docbook.xml and docbook-style.xsl in rootDirectory/doc, and we put the generated PDF in rootDirectory/docs (/pdf).

Here is an example of a docbook stylesheet that you can use: http://cl.ly/2n1p3o0r1L3Z1d2U4345

To generate the PDF, from the terminal, go to the directory where the file build.gradle is and execute

```
gradle docbookPdf
```

if you named the task 'docbookPdf'.

That's it. It should work on any platform.